# Retrieve CSV content using AXIOS GET and VUE JS - returns time out error

Tags: vue.js, csv, axios

I have a CSV file from an external host.

I'd like to retrieve the content of the CSV file and read it in my VUE JS component.

For example,
CSV location: `https://my-host.com/file-name.csv`

```
let host = 'https://host-name.com/';
let filePath = 'file-name.csv';
try {
  let response = await axios.get(`${host}${filePath}`, {}, {});
  this.csv = response.data;
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

I get the following error: `net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`:

```
Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:69)
```

I've tried to configure axios with:

`axios.defaults.timeout = 500000;`

Any other suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem.
Can't access external URL from the front-end due to `cors policy`.

Open a server endpoint that deals with external file access.
The front-end reaches the new endpoint which returns the file's content.